# Line spacing/height Issue in textbox of HTML in SSRS

Tags: html, reporting-services

I have placed a textbox and set the placeholder Markup as HTML in SSRS.

Below is the HTML:

```
    <DIV STYLE="text-align:Justify;font-family:Georgia;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:16;color:#000000;"><P STYLE="text-align:Left;font-family:Calibri;font-size:14.666666666666666;margin:0 0 0 0;"><SPAN><SPAN>Ref.: </SPAN></SPAN><SPAN><SPAN>&lt;&lt;Reference&gt;&gt;</SPAN></SPAN></P><P STYLE="text-align:Left;font-family:Calibri;font-size:14.666666666666666;margin:0 0 0 0;"><SPAN><SPAN>Location: </SPAN></SPAN><SPAN><SPAN>&lt;&lt;Room&gt;&gt;</SPAN></SPAN></P><P STYLE="text-align:Left;font-family:Calibri;font-size:14.666666666666666;margin:0 0 0 0;"><SPAN><SPAN>Size : </SPAN></SPAN><SPAN><SPAN>&lt;&lt;Size&gt;&gt;</SPAN></SPAN></P><P STYLE="text-align:Left;font-family:Calibri;font-size:14.666666666666666;margin:0 0 0 0;"><SPAN><SPAN>&lt;&lt;Option 01&gt;&gt;</SPAN></SPAN><SPAN><SPAN>  </SPAN></SPAN><SPAN><SPAN>&lt;&lt;Answer 01&gt;&gt;</SPAN></SPAN></P><P STYLE="text-align:Left;font-family:Calibri;font-size:14.666666666666666;margin:0 0 0 0;"><SPAN><SPAN>&lt;&lt;Option 02&gt;&gt;</SPAN></SPAN><SPAN><SPAN>  </SPAN></SPAN><SPAN><SPAN>&lt;&lt;Answer 02&gt;&gt;</SPAN></SPAN></P><P STYLE="text-align:Left;font-family:Calibri;font-size:14.666666666666666;margin:0 0 0 0;"><SPAN><SPAN>&lt;&lt;Option 03&gt;&gt;</SPAN></SPAN><SPAN><SPAN>  </SPAN></SPAN><SPAN><SPAN>&lt;&lt;Answer 03&gt;&gt;</SPAN></SPAN></P><P /></DIV>
```

When I run the report, it should give output like below:

```
Ref.: <<Reference>>
Location: <<Room>>
Size : <<Size>>
<<Option 01>> <<Answer 01>>
<<Option 02>> <<Answer 02>>
<<Option 03>> <<Answer 03>>
```

But it is showing with extra line like below:

```
Ref.: <<Reference>>

Location: <<Room>>

Size : <<Size>>

<<Option 01>> <<Answer 01>>

<<Option 02>> <<Answer 02>>

<<Option 03>> <<Answer 03>>
```

I have tried by changing the Line Spacing but it has NO impact on output.

I do not understand why

tag is adding extra padding after each line except last line.

Please suggest some solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I copied it to a jsfiddle and it seems to work fine, try inspecting it and see if some of the css is overwritten by some other class

Comment: I think SSRS only supports some basic HTML tags.You might need to use some old school HTML with  a single paragraph and line breaks <br> etc